# Calculate difference between two datetimes

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am using PHP and MySQL, and want to calculate date time difference between two datetimes. I have a message table, in that table `createdate` is one field. I want to find out day and time difference from current date in the format `1 day 2 hours ago`. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 6):

Use PHP's built in date functions:

```
<?php
    $start_time = "Y-m-d H:i:s"; // fill this in with actual time in this format
    $end_time = "Y-m-d H:i:s"; // fill this in with actual time in this format

    // both of the above formats are the same as what MySQL stores its
    // DATETIMEs in

    $start = new DateTime($start_time);
    $interval = $start->diff(new DateTime($end_time));

    echo $interval->format("d \d\a\y\s h \h\o\u\r\s");
```

- [DateInterval documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)
- [DateTime::diff documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: What about <= PHP 5.2 ?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,createdate,NOW()) as diff_in_hours FROM table1;
```

Then on php side you can easily convert the value of `diff_in_hours` to days + hours format.

Comment: @Sanjay: The solution I wrote gives the time difference up to a fraction of a sec in the following format `HH:MM:ss.s`

Comment: @Sanjay: The first argument of `TIMESTAMPDIFF` can also be `MINUTE` ,or `SECOND`, or `MICROSECOND` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff). In your question you asked about days+hours, so I put `HOUR` unit to my sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEDIFF()` and `TIMEDIFF()` functions in MySQL.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), createdate) AS output_day, 
TIMEDIFF(CURDATE(), createdate) AS output_time 
FROM message_table
```

For output_day it is already in day unit. But output_time require additional manipulation to get the hour part of the time difference.

Hope this helps.