# Get remaining days, hours and minutes using mySql

Tags: mysql

I am stuck in getting the remaining days, hours and minutes between two dates in mySql.

I have an expiry date and I want to compare it with current DateTime and want to get days, hours and minutes.

Comment: [Can you show us anything you've tried so far?]

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: There are days, hours and minutes represented in a DateTime. Tell us specifically what human-readable format you're trying to render, what you tried so far, and how its results differed.

Comment: This is my solution. <br /> SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,NOW(), Offer.Expiry) AS DAY,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,NOW(), Offer.Expiry)-TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,NOW(), Offer.Expiry)*24 AS HOUR,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(), Offer.Expiry)-TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,NOW(), Offer.Expiry)*60 AS MINUTE
FROM Offer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602907/calculate-difference-between-two-datetimes) may help you. There is many way to calculate difference between two dates and your are not oblige to do this in full SQL.

[EDIT]

I ve found a solution in SQL...

```
SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,NOW(),'2012-01-01') AS DAY,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,NOW(),'2012-01-01')-TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,NOW(),'2012-01-01')*24 AS HOUR,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),'2012-01-01')-TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,NOW(),'2012-01-01')*60 AS MINUTE;
```

Comment: I agree that it is not an answer, but this link treats a similar problem and i think it can helps him. If i were him i would not have tried to do this in SQL... That's the reason why I said that there is many other way to solve his problem (programmaticaly)

Answer (score 3):

You should try to get the difference between these two values (e.g. as a timestamp) and format the date in you application. You can get the current timestamp with NOW(). 
If you want MySQL to format your data you should take a look at the manual. There are several functions for that.