# How to obtaining remaining available days in a month for booking?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table for slots that have the following Schema

```
SlotId
FromDate
ToDate
```

I want to get the remaining days in that given month available for slot booking.

To be clear, I am trying to retrieve all the dates apart from the dates stored in the database(as those are already booked) for a given month.

For example, if a record have `FromDate` is equal to `2014-04-02` and `ToDate` is equal to `2014-04-06` I am expecting the following result:

```
2014-04-01
2014-04-07
...
2014-04-30
```

Although i am scripting in PHP, I am little curious about the query to accomplish this.

Comment: What is the data type of those *dates*?

Comment: I have assigned DATE as the Datatype for both FromDate and ToDate

Comment: Is your booking available every day during the remaining days or do you have exceptions?

Comment: No exceptions, It is available all through the month

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836384/get-remaining-days-hours-and-minutes-using-mysql

Comment: @JohnRuddell: An argument is going on that a similar answer given is not as what OP asked.

Comment: that would be part of the answer.. just a reference

Comment: I think to do what you wish with pure MySQL you would need to use a stored procedure/trigger you would probably get this done easier on your PHP code

Comment: no its possible... im doing it right now... but what date do you want to use? (fromdate or todate)??

Comment: Actually We have to consider both fromdate and todate. So that we can eliminate these in between dates.. Or You can suggest any other table structure so that things get easy. you are welcome

Comment: @JohnRuddell from and to are the days booked which should be removed from the resulting days, so basically he wants to read both from and to for all records on the database pertinent to that month(not excluding booking that started on the previous month and get into the current month, I assume) and return only the days that are not already booked.

Comment: @Prix Great that's what i meant.

Comment: so the days before the from and to and the days after from and to correct? (because inbetween from and to it would be booked)

Comment: Yes it is @JohnRuddell

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes, for all the records on the database so if he have for instance from `2014-01-01` to `2014-01-10` and another record with from `2014-01-12` to `2014-01-31` then you only have 1 day available on that month. But you also need to consider records like for instance from `2013-12-29` to `2014-01-05` I believe, not sure if he allows that kind of setup or if he parts it away into 2.

Comment: @Ramaraju.d: Are you grouping the dates by `slotid` or month of dates?

Comment: @Ravinder he can't group it by month, if a booking start on the previous month you won't know the limiters. See my comment above.

Comment: @Prix: That can be understandable. OP seems not clear on how and what to ask. His question says *`if a record`* then it sounds like row based filtering.

Comment: @Ravinder that was an example, and he also provided what would be the result if that record was the only record on the table. `2014-04-01 - 2014-04-07` as you can see on the result he skipped the days between which is related to the record booked.

Comment: How many do you allow per month? like bookings? is there a minimum day requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is not an easy thing to do in mysql but here is something that should work. this gets the dates in any given month that are not booked... see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53fdcc/3) for working example

```
SELECT *, union_month.day_date
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS day_date UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12 UNION ALL
    SELECT 13 UNION ALL
    SELECT 14 UNION ALL
    SELECT 15 UNION ALL
    SELECT 16 UNION ALL
    SELECT 17 UNION ALL
    SELECT 18 UNION ALL
    SELECT 19 UNION ALL
    SELECT 20 UNION ALL
    SELECT 21 UNION ALL
    SELECT 22 UNION ALL
    SELECT 23 UNION ALL
    SELECT 24 UNION ALL
    SELECT 25 UNION ALL
    SELECT 26 UNION ALL
    SELECT 27 UNION ALL
    SELECT 28 UNION ALL
    SELECT 29 UNION ALL
    SELECT 30 UNION ALL
    SELECT 31
) AS union_month
LEFT JOIN myTable AS t ON union_month.day_date <> DAY(t.to_date) OR union_month.day_date <> DAY(t.from_date)
WHERE union_month.day_date <= DAY(LAST_DAY(t.to_date))
AND union_month.day_date NOT BETWEEN DAY(t.from_date) AND DAY(t.to_date)
GROUP BY union_month.day_date
```

---

for multiple dates in a month change the WHERE clause to this

```
WHERE
      union_month.day_date <= DAY(LAST_DAY(t.to_date))
      AND union_month.day_date not BETWEEN (select DAY(from_date) from myTable limit 0,1) AND (select DAY(to_date) from myTable limit 0,1)
      AND union_month.day_date not BETWEEN (select DAY(from_date) from myTable limit 1,1) AND (select DAY(to_date) from myTable limit 1,1)
      AND union_month.day_date not BETWEEN (select DAY(from_date) from myTable limit 2,1) AND (select DAY(to_date) from myTable limit 2,1)
GROUP BY union_month.day_date
```

working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea9a61/10) for multiple dates

Comment: And what happens when you have multiple records for a given month? According to your fiddle if you add a second record it fails.

Comment: you can do a date not between for each of the dates.. but you would need to know the number of stays/bookings.

Comment: Its best to do this in another programming language with the given date. or `create` a calendar table to join.... best way to do this is to just do a `while (start_date <= from_date)` and `while(to_date <= end_date)` ... in another programming language.. the end_date and the start_date could be part of the sql select and the rest would be easy from there... I can add that to the answer if the OP would like

Comment: That's exactly why I have mentioned `to do what you wish with pure MySQL you would need to use a stored procedure/trigger` and you soon mentioned `no its possible... im doing it right now...` but you have had no solution that does it as of yet with pure MySQL.

Comment: I did do something that works... and i also did it for multiple dates in a month.. problem is you have to basically hardcode it.. it is possible but not recommended.

Comment: The only version you showed was one that works for a single record which is IMHO is useless if you need it working for several records after all a table is not made of single records. `basically hardcode it.. it is possible but not recommended` which goes back to what I had previously mentioned ;)

Comment: I know lol... thats why i said its possible (as opposed to it being impossible) and I was working on a solution.. but yea i never said its recommended.. heres a working example with 3 dates in a month - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea9a61/10

Comment: Could probably improve a lot if you use triggers which will most likely remove the hard code dependency.

Comment: yea I was looking into that but it was like 3AM and i got tired lol... the code is there and can be modified by anyone if they would like :) ill update my answer to include multiples

Comment: triggers would be a good solution because you can do something like `FOR EACH ROW` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: You people are Awesome, Thank you very much. i will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

You need remaining days count or dates which are free?

Comment: Dates which are free. i mean this "I want all the dates Apart from the dates stored in the database(these dates are already booked) for a given month"

Comment: If you are using programming language, you can do it using array. store booked dates in one array and compare those dates with another array of dates for particular month. If you want to use alternative for query then only.

Comment: Yes, but just to know if there is a tricky way to accomplish this with a query

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this. May it will help you. 
 You need to use this query in loop. with some variables.
 In example I have consider April month only. You can do it for all months.

```
SELECT distinct * FROM (SELECT DATE_ADD('2014-04-01', INTERVAL t4+t16+t64+t256+t1024 DAY) freedays  FROM 
(SELECT 0 t4    UNION ALL SELECT 1   UNION ALL SELECT 2   UNION ALL SELECT 3  ) t4,
(SELECT 0 t16   UNION ALL SELECT 4   UNION ALL SELECT 8   UNION ALL SELECT 12 ) t16,   
(SELECT 0 t64   UNION ALL SELECT 16  UNION ALL SELECT 32  UNION ALL SELECT 48 ) t64,      
(SELECT 0 t256  UNION ALL SELECT 64  UNION ALL SELECT 128 UNION ALL SELECT 192) t256,     
(SELECT 0 t1024 UNION ALL SELECT 256 UNION ALL SELECT 512 UNION ALL SELECT 768) t1024     
) b 
 WHERE freedays not between (select FrmDate from slotbooking limit 1) and (select ToDate from
  slotbooking limit 1) and freedays < '2014-04-30';
```

Comment: It may not perfect but logic is there. You can modify it.

Comment: [what about multiple records along the month?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77b6cb/1) Your example will work for a single record but on his table he will have multiple booking dates for a given month or that may start on the previous month and partially gets into current month.

Comment: @Prix Need to use counter to get FrmDate and ToDate in between clause.

Comment: Your answer as is, would not solve the OP question. It does however partially answer it.

Comment: @Prix Yes. That's why I mention my first comment. :D